# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException when creating the result Excel file using Java in Webdriver

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, webdriver

Getting java.lang.NullPointerException when creating the result Excel file using Java in Webdriver.

First row in the created results excel file is created and for the 2nd row it is giving "java.lang.NullPointerException" at workbook.write() ie. wwb.write() in my code.

Please find the code i have written and error received.

```
public class AccProfile_Zipfield_Validations1 extends SiteSecurity_FieldValidations
{
String msg = null;
// Creating New Account Profile
@Test
public void AccountProfile_City_Validations() throws IOException, BiffException, InterruptedException, RowsExceededException, WriteException
//public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, BiffException, InterruptedException, RowsExceededException, WriteException
{
    // creating properties files storing the ID's and xpaths
    APPLICATION_LOGS.debug("Starting the test suite");
    APPLICATION_LOGS.debug("Loading config files");
    config = new Properties();
    //FileInputStream fp = new FileInputStream("./config.properties");
    FileInputStream fp = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\com\\ode\\utility\\config.properties");
    config.load(fp);
    APPLICATION_LOGS.debug("Loading Object XPATHS");
    OR = new Properties();
    //FileInputStream fp1 = new FileInputStream("./OR.properties");
    FileInputStream fp1 = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\com\\ode\\utility\\OR.properties");
    OR.load(fp1);

    //Sleep Times
    long Admin_edit = Long.valueOf(config.getProperty("config_edit")); 
    long Admin_zipcode = Long.valueOf(config.getProperty("config_zipcode"));
    long Admin_cityfield = Long.valueOf(config.getProperty("config_cityfield"));    
    long Admin_screenshot = Long.valueOf(config.getProperty("config_screenshot"));
    long Admin_checkbox = Long.valueOf(config.getProperty("config_checkbox")); 
    long Admin_save = Long.valueOf(config.getProperty("config_save")); 

    //Take the data from input xls file
    //FileInputStream fi =new FileInputStream("./Credit_Admin_Login.xls");
    FileInputStream fi =new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\com\\ode\\resources\\Credit_AdminUser_Login.xls");
    Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);
    Sheet sh = wb.getSheet("Credit_AdminUserLogin");

    //Take the data from input xls file
    //FileInputStream fi =new FileInputStream("./Credit_AccProfile_FV.xls");
    FileInputStream fi1 =new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\com\\ode\\resources\\Credit_AccProfile_FV.xls");
    Workbook wb1 = Workbook.getWorkbook(fi1);
    Sheet sh1 = wb1.getSheet("700Credit_FieldValidations_City");

    //Create the Result xls file
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("./700Credit_AccProfile_FV_"+cdate+".xls");
    WritableWorkbook wwb = Workbook.createWorkbook(fo);
    WritableSheet ws = wwb.createSheet("700Credit_FV_City_Results", 0);
    System.out.println(ws.getName());
    Thread.sleep(Admin_screenshot); 

    System.out.println("   ******** City field validations ******** "); 
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Random Number generated: "+Randnum);
    System.out.println("Name for Account creation: "+AccName+"_City_"+Randnum);
    System.out.println("Current Date generated: "+cdate);

    APPLICATION_LOGS.debug("Starting the driver");
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

    driver.get(config.getProperty("Testwebsite"));
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    for (int i = 1; i < sh.getRows(); i++)
    {   
        driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("signIN_username_ID"))).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("signIN_username_ID"))).sendKeys(sh.getCell(0, i).getContents());
        driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("signIN_password_ID"))).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("signIN_password_ID"))).sendKeys(sh.getCell(1, i).getContents());
        driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("signIN_LogIN_ID"))).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("Logged in as Site Admin User");

        //Click on Add New button
        driver.findElement(By.name(OR.getProperty("AddNew_AccProf_ID"))).click();
        Thread.sleep(Admin_edit);
        System.out.println("Clicked on Add button for creating New Account");

        //Entering data in the Account Information section
        driver.findElement(By.name(OR.getProperty("AccName_Id"))).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.name(OR.getProperty("AccName_Id"))).sendKeys(AccName+"_City_"+Randnum);
        driver.findElement(By.name(OR.getProperty("AccDBA_ID"))).sendKeys("Kumar_DBA");     

        String accTaxId = OR.getProperty("AccTax_ID");
        WebElement accTaxInput = driver.findElement(By.id(accTaxId));
        accTaxInput.clear();
        accTaxInput.sendKeys(String.valueOf(12345));
        accTaxInput = driver.findElement(By.id(accTaxId));

        driver.findElement(By.name(OR.getProperty("AccAddress_ID"))).sendKeys("124 - City Cross Roads");

        String accZipID = OR.getProperty("AccZip_ID"); 
        WebElement accZipInput = driver.findElement(By.id(accZipID));
        accZipInput.clear(); 
        accZipInput.sendKeys(String.valueOf(79081));
        accZipInput = driver.findElement(By.id(accZipID));
        new Actions(driver).sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("AccZip_ID"))), "").perform();
        Thread.sleep(Admin_zipcode);

        //Entering data in the Main Contact Information section 
        driver.findElement(By.name(OR.getProperty("AccFName_ID"))).sendKeys("Peter");
        Thread.sleep(Admin_cityfield);

        for (int j=1; j<sh1.getRows(); j++)
        {               
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Test Scenario - "+sh1.getCell(3, j).getContents());
            if(j==1)
            {
                //Sending Numeric values to City Field. 
                driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("AccCity_ID"))).clear();
                driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("AccCity_ID"))).sendKeys(sh1.getCell(1, j).getContents());
                Thread.sleep(Admin_zipcode);
                //Switch the driver context to the alert
                Alert alertDialog = driver.switchTo().alert();
                //Get the alert text
                String alertText = alertDialog.getText();
                System.out.println("Message displayed on Popup Window when entered "+sh1.getCell(5, j).getContents()+" in City field: "+alertText);
                //Click the OK button on the alert.
                alertDialog.accept();
                msg = alertText;

                //Taking Screen shot of the Application
                File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("./screenshots\\Admin_AccProfile_Field_Level_Validations_"+cdate+"\\Cityfield\\Admin_AccountProfile_"+sh1.getCell(5, j).getContents()+" in City field.jpg"));
                Thread.sleep(Admin_checkbox);   
            }
            else if (j==2)
            {
                driver.findElement(By.name(OR.getProperty("AccFName_ID"))).sendKeys("Peter");
                driver.findElement(By.name(OR.getProperty("AccMName_ID"))).sendKeys("S");
                driver.findElement(By.name(OR.getProperty("AccLName_ID"))).sendKeys("Mark");

                driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("save_ID"))).click();
                Thread.sleep(Admin_cityfield);
                Alert alertDialog = driver.switchTo().alert();
                //Get the alert text
                String alertText = alertDialog.getText();
                System.out.println("Message displayed on Popup Window when City field is left blank: "+alertText);
                //Click the OK button on the alert.
                alertDialog.accept();
                msg = alertText;

                //Taking Screen shot of the Application
                File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("./screenshots\\Admin_AccProfile_Field_Level_Validations_"+cdate+"\\Cityfield\\Admin_AccountProfile_with_Cityfield_blank.jpg"));
                Thread.sleep(Admin_zipcode);        

                driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("save_ID"))).click();
                Thread.sleep(Admin_zipcode);
                alertDialog = driver.switchTo().alert();
                //Get the alert text
                alertText = alertDialog.getText();
                //Click the OK button on the alert.
                alertDialog.accept();

                //driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("AccCity_ID"))).sendKeys("GENERAL ELECTRIC");
                driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("AccCity_ID"))).sendKeys(sh1.getCell(1, j).getContents());

                //Taking Screen shot of the Application
                scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("./screenshots\\Admin_AccProfile_Field_Level_Validations_"+cdate+"\\Cityfield\\Admin_AccountProfile_with_Cityfield_other city name.jpg"));
                Thread.sleep(Admin_screenshot);

                String accOffNoID = OR.getProperty("AccOffNo_ID"); 
                WebElement accOffNoInput = driver.findElement(By.id(accOffNoID));
                accOffNoInput.clear(); 
                accOffNoInput.sendKeys(String.valueOf(9874651230L));
                accOffNoInput = driver.findElement(By.id(accOffNoID));

                String accCellNoID = OR.getProperty("AccCellNo_ID"); 
                WebElement accCellNoInput = driver.findElement(By.id(accCellNoID));
                accCellNoInput.clear(); 
                accCellNoInput.sendKeys(String.valueOf(9632587110L));
                accCellNoInput = driver.findElement(By.id(accCellNoID));

                String accFaxNoID = OR.getProperty("AccFaxNo_ID"); 
                WebElement accFaxNoInput = driver.findElement(By.id(accFaxNoID));
                accFaxNoInput.clear(); 
                accFaxNoInput.sendKeys(String.valueOf(9512368741L));
                accFaxNoInput = driver.findElement(By.id(accFaxNoID));

                driver.findElement(By.name(OR.getProperty("AccEmail_ID"))).sendKeys("abc@abc.com");
                driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("txtNAD_ID"))).sendKeys("LE0472");

                System.out.println("Entered all the required information for creating the Account");

                driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("save_ID"))).click();
                Thread.sleep(Admin_save);
                System.out.println("Successfully created the Account: "+AccName+"_City_"+Randnum);

                //Taking Screen shot of the Application
                scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("./screenshots\\Admin_AccProfile_Field_Level_Validations_"+cdate+"\\Cityfield\\Admin_NewAccountCreated.jpg"));
                Thread.sleep(Admin_screenshot); 
                System.out.println();
                driver.close();
            }

            for (int k = 0; k < sh1.getColumns(); k++) 
            {
                Label lab=new Label(k,j,sh1.getCell(k, j).getContents());   
                ws.addCell(lab);
                Label result = new Label(2,j, msg);
                ws.addCell(result);
                String c2String = sh1.getCell(2, j).getContents().toString();
                if(c2String.equalsIgnoreCase(msg))
                {
                    Label status=new Label(5,j,"Pass");
                    ws.addCell(status);
                }
                else
                {
                    Label status=new Label(5,j,"Fail");
                    ws.addCell(status);
                }
            }

            //Add the 4 Labels

            Label un= new Label(0,0,"Test Data");
            Label pw= new Label(1,0,"City Code");
            Label Desc= new Label(2,0,"Error Message");
            Label st= new Label(3,0,"Scenario#");
            Label tsd = new Label(4,0,"Test Scenario Description"); 
            Label rs = new Label(5,0,"Results");
            ws.addCell(un);
            ws.addCell(pw);
            ws.addCell(Desc);
            ws.addCell(st);
            ws.addCell(tsd);
            ws.addCell(rs);
            wwb.write();
            wwb.close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Error Message received:

```
FAILED: AccountProfile_City_Validations
java.lang.NullPointerException
at jxl.write.biff.File.write(File.java:149)
at jxl.write.biff.WritableWorkbookImpl.write(WritableWorkbookImpl.java:697)
at com.ode.Admin.AccProfile_Zipfield_Validations1.AccountProfile_City_Validations(AccProfile_Zipfield_Validations1.java:258)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1203)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1128)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1036)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Please help me out with this issue. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: System.out.println(ws.getName()); - does print something? If yes, than WB created and you have added a field somethere, which is empty ( has no data initialized)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It will print just the sheet name created in the result Excel file. It has nothing to do with code. Today I have run again by commenting that line. Still received the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea, maybe it helps:

The `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` and other wait functions are because this is a multithreaded environment.

In most cases the wait, sleep is good, easy fast solution can be, until strange behavior doesn't happen a few times, than you are checking what is wrong.

I would like to suggest to spend a bit more time on the code review and remove all sleep and wait functions and do synchronized blocks, functions instead, and thread join as how is needed in multithreaded environment.

Probably statement1 need to write something and you say: wait 30 sec, than your workbook try to write to the file and only after the 30 sec elapsed will be executed the statement1 , which should set a field value. At the moment, when workbook write to the file it isn't set the field1, by statement1.

Other idea:

Place a breakpoint at line : `wwb.write();`
There investigate which field has no value.

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried the second method and it doesn't worked. I have moved the statement wwb.Close() to outside the loop. Now i am not getting the Null pointer Exception.

Comment: not at close you need, but where I told, and you have to check internal values ( hundred of variables, if not thousands ) Your know what field has no value. The real fix will be the solution 1

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code by moving the add cells and labels and pasted after closing the for loop. Then it worked fine for me. Thanks for all who have replied to my question.

moved code:
    //Add the Labels

```
Label un= new Label(0,0,"Test Data");
Label pw= new Label(1,0,"City Code");
Label Desc= new Label(2,0,"Error Message");
Label st= new Label(3,0,"Scenario#");
Label tsd = new Label(4,0,"Test Scenario Description"); 
Label rs = new Label(5,0,"Results");
ws.addCell(un);
ws.addCell(pw);
ws.addCell(Desc);
ws.addCell(st);
ws.addCell(tsd);
ws.addCell(rs);
wwb.write();
wwb.close();
```